# Is there a way in Flutter to navigate to a page gradually by sliding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation

Here is my problem.
I would like that by dragging progressively (with my finger for example) up a container (Container) that this one moves following the movement but that a new page (NewPage) towards which I want to navigate is supperposed on the container while following the movement until a certain level when I release, that the page takes all the screen. (Let's say I want to do a Navigator.push but in this sense).

[image: Something like this]

Thank you.

```dart
class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
   ...
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(...);
   }
}

...

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
   ...
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
         body: Stack(
            children: [
               ...
               GestureDetector(
                  child: Positioned(
                     ...
                     child: Container()
                  )
               )
            ]
         )
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But try these different navigation techniques.

1. [Hero Animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)
2. [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) - Try this with `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I just modified the question to try to make it clearer.
Otherwise what I want is to navigate to another view.